# Physical path of outlook,lync history

Tags: windows, outlook-2013, lync-2013

can some one know , where  Outlook and Lync stores history (conversations , Contacts......).in windows 8.1 . 
**I want to know the path of files** . I'm not interested in settings and export history in csv file .
I know that informations are stored in server but there is other information stored in client Desktop .I find useless informations (signature ... )
**I want just the physical path** . Thanks

Comment: Please i need an answer  , help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the path of these files : Recuperate information from cache of outlook ,lync in this Path
C:\Users\XXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook 
C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync
With different Format .dat .ost .BAK .odb  .
And then you can try to recuperate their content .